# Displaying requests module logging messages whilst using a .yaml config file for logging module

Tags: python, logging, yaml

How might I display the `requests` module logging messages whilst using a .yaml file to configure the `logging` module?

Previously I have used the following to display logging output from `requests`, but I'm now lost:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
#logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

My .yaml file, which has replaced the above code:

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    stream: ext://sys.stderr
    formatter: basic
  audit_file:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    filename: bot_log.logging
    encoding: utf-8
    formatter: basic
formatters:
  basic:
    style: "{"
    format: "{asctime:s} {levelname:s}: {name:s}: {message:s}"
    datefmt: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
loggers:
  verbose:
    handlers: [console]
    level: DEBUG
    propagate: False
  audit:
    handlers: [audit_file]
    level: DEBUG
root:
  handlers: [console]
  level: INFO
```

How I now load and configure the `logging` in my application:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with LoggingConfig():
        with TradeHub() as th:
            th.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` itself does not log anything, all the logging is emitted from the `urllib3` package. Just add a configuration section for the `requests.packages.urllib3` logger:

```
loggers:
  verbose:
    handlers: [console]
    level: DEBUG
    propagate: False
  audit:
    handlers: [audit_file]
    level: DEBUG
  requests.packages.urllib3:
    propagate: True
    level: DEBUG
root:
  handlers: [console]
  level: INFO
```

Although afaik all the `urllib3`'s logging output has `DEBUG` level, so you won't catch anything as long as your `root` logger has `INFO` level. For example, this snippet won't print anything (`logging.yaml` is the config file):

```
import logging.config
import yaml
import requests


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('logging.yaml', 'rt') as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

Change the root logger's level to `DEBUG` to get the debug output:

```
2018-02-22 13:52:21 DEBUG: urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): stackoverflow.com
2018-02-22 13:52:21 DEBUG: urllib3.connectionpool: https://stackoverflow.com:443 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 36997
```